# How to Generate a Remote maven repository without installing maven : for Gradle usage

Tags: maven, gradle

We in our project are using gradle as a build tool. Until now we kept some of the thirdparty dependencies in our local systems and we used them from there only (defined flatdir in gradle script to use those dependencies). Now the requirement is to create a common repository on some server so that everybody use dependencies from that common repository (a maven repository).

The question is how can I create a maven remote repository without maven setup on it as I am having gradle as a build tool in that system.

1> Is it compulsory to have maven setup on the system if I want to create a maven remote repository?

2> Is it only possible from nexus or artifactory tools? or I can do it without use of any other tool?

Comment: 1) no maven necessary; 2) while not strictly necessary, this is by far the easiest option.

Comment: How is it possible to create one without using Nexus or Artifactory? I need some guidance on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you only have to place the files in the correct locations to form a valid repository. Whether you do this as Maven repository or Ivy repository doesn't matter really, both are just about following conventions on where to place which files.

You could also create some Gradle script that publishes those libraries to the central repository I think. But don't ask me how exactly, I never did this for a Maven repository. I just did this once to create and maintain a central Ivy repository with Ant. but as Ant is a first-class citizen in Gradle, this could probably also be made in Gradle.

Comment: **Actually you only have to place the files in the correct locations to form a valid repository.**   Means no need to explicitly do anything to identify it as a remote repository?

Comment: Nope, not really. A Maven or Ivy repository is just a bunch of files that are in pre-defined places following a pattern. Tools like Nexus or Artifactory just do the maintenance of putting the files in place and so on for you, but you can equally well just put the files in place and access this via network drive or a simple http server serving the files.

Answer (score 1):

There's two main players when it comes to artifact repositories

1. [Sonatype Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/)
2. [JFrog Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/Artifactory/)

There's no need to install Maven to use either. Both can be used from either Maven or Gradle

Comment: Thanks for answering but I tried using nexus and result was not as expected. Gradle was searching file in a location like this:       

What went wrong: 
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'. 
> Could not find GroupName:DependencyName:Version. 
Searched in the following locations: 
http://localhost:Port/nexus/content/repositories/MyRepoName/Dependencies/**GroupName/DependencyName/Version**/DependencyName-Version.jar
While it should seach for the dependencies in the path **/repositories/MyRepoName/Dependencies/**

Comment: Find a gradle/nexus tutorial and follow it. If you want help here you'll need to show what you've done. Try hitting the nexus URL in your browser. Once you understand the URL pattern, configure the repo in your Gradle script